# Wildcard redirect https://www.*.abc.com to *.abc.com nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy, web, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to redirect all traffic from

**www.*.abc.com** to  ***.abc.com**  without www prefix .
i have 1000+ subdomains on the same application which use only one nginx virtual host file in sites enabled directory .

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a regular expression `server_name` to capture the part of the domain after the `www`. For example:

```
server_name ~^www\.(?<domain>.*\.example\.com)$;
return 301 $domain$request_uri;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

Comment: i have this domain - https://www.*.eu.engagementhq.com . Which i am trying to configure like follows - 
server_name ~^www\.(?<domain>.*\.engagementhq\.com)$;
return 301 $domain$request_uri;  
but this does not work .

Comment: To help you with your specific problem, we would need to see your configuration (use: `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files), relevant entries from the access and error logs, and `curl -I` showing the actual and expected responses.